# Convert PHP SoapClient to Perl SOAP::Lite

Tags: php, perl, soap-client, soaplite, five9

I am writing a web application that works with the five9 API. I have a working php script that uses the API to print out the email of the first User. My application is in Perl and I am trying to avoid shelling out to a PHP script. I have tried to use SOAP::Lite but am having difficulties. Here is my working PHP script.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

$soap = null;
$wsdl = "https://api.five9.com/wsadmin/v2/AdminWebService?wsdl";

$user = "johnsmith@example.com";
$pass = "password";

$soap_options = array("login" => $user, "password" => $pass, "trace" => 1);

$soap = new SoapClient($wsdl, $soap_options);

$arryParams['userNamePattern'] = '';

$result = $soap->getUsersInfo($arryParams);

if(isset($result->return)) {
    $objRecords = $result->return;
    print $objRecords[0]->generalInfo->EMail;
    print "\n";

}

?>
```

Here is what I have so far working with perl and SOAP::Lite

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use MIME::Base64;
use Data::Dumper;
use SOAP::Lite +trace => [ transport => sub { print $_[0]->as_string } ];

my $wsdl_five9 = 'https://api.five9.com/wsadmin/AdminWebService?wsdl&user=johnsmith@example.com';
my $uri  = 'https://api.five9.com/wsadmin/AdminWebService';
my $user = 'johnsmith@example.com';
my $password = 'password';

my $authorize = 'Basic '.encode_base64($user . ":" . $password);

my $client = SOAP::Lite->service($wsdl_five9);

$client->on_fault(
    sub {
        my $soap = shift;
        my $res = shift;

        if(ref($res) eq '') {
            die($res);
        } else {
            die($res->faultstring);
        }
        return new SOAP::SOM;
    }
    );

print "Done\n";
```

If anyone has experience working with perl and SOAP any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You will need to show your Perl code that is giving you problems.

Comment: What difficulties are you having. people would want at least a copy of the error and a minimum amount of code to replicate the issue.

Comment: SO =/= Code conversion service

Comment: It is not clear what is going wrong: give us clues about what you except and what happen.